# Drag and drop events for image file upload not working in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I need help with my image upload function for drag and drop.

I get a nice box saying I can drag and drop images but my console's is saying:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: drag is not defined**
**Uncaught ReferenceError: drop is not defined**
**Uncaught ReferenceError: dragNdrop is not defined**

When I'm clicking and drag images.

What am I missing?

Here's a sample of my code:

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInputFile">Ladda upp bild</label>
    <input ref="fileInput" type="file" id="imageInputFile" 
                click.delegate="previewImage()">
</div>
<strong>OR</strong>

<span class="dragBox">
    Drag and Drop image here
    <input type="file" onChange="dragNdrop(event)" ondragover="drag()" ondrop="drop()" id="imageInputFile" />
</span>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

js

```
  dragNdrop(event) {
    let fileName = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    let previewImg = document.createElement("img");
    previewImg.setAttribute("src", fileName);
    preview.innerHTML = "";
    preview.appendChild(previewImg);
  }
  drag() {
    document.getElementById('imageInputFile').parentNode.className = 'draging dragBox';
  }
  drop() {
    document.getElementById('imageInputFile').parentNode.className = 'dragBox';
  }
```

EDIT HTML

```
<span class="dragBox">
    Click here or drag images here
    <input ref="fileInput" type="file" change.trigger="dragNdrop($event)" 
                dragover.delegate="drag()" drop.delegate="drop()" 
                id="imageInputFile" />
</span>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

my regular button for image upload works to add a new image, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Are `dragNdrop` and other functions inside a class or are those global functions?

Comment: They're in a class called **add-car.js** and my html is in **add-car.html**. And as the name reveals, its a module for adding a car to DB. I haven't declared any variables or anything for the drag and drop function. I just assume it listens to the imageInputFile id as in my buttonuploader

Comment: Try changing them to: `drop.delegate="drop()"` and `dragover.delegate="drag()" ` and `change.trigger = dragNdrop($event)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked almost perfect!
Now I can click the box for fileupload and preview my image. But I cant drag and drop the image and preview the image

Comment: There's no errors, and when I hover over my upload box I can see the image name but it doesn't preview my image

Comment: Why do you have two `file` inputs here? If the first one is only there for previewing then you can use a button?

Comment: The issue here is probably because you have **two elements** with `imageInputFile` id and `getElementById` returns the wrong one. If you can clarify the 2 `file` inputs, I can suggest a pure aurelia solution instead of using the DOM API

Comment: I edited my code, see original post.
Now I only have a box for either click or drag. When I click I can upload a image and preview it, but when I drag it says "No files chosen".
EDIT: Now I got the error message: **Uncaught Error: previewImage is not a function**

Comment: Change this to: `drop.delegate="dragNdrop($event)"`. My guess is `change.trigger` is never called on drag and drop. (It will persist the `draging ` class. Don't worry about that for now)

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks, that did the trick! I'll accept your answer, but can you please explain why the change.trigger is never called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you use HTML attributes like `onChange`, `ondragover` etc without `delegate`, it will look for a `drag` function in the global scope. And not in the instance of the aurelia's viewmodel bound to this view. You need to use `delegate` to let aurelia know that the instance of your class must be used.
- You have two elements with the same `id` in your HTML. `getElementById('imageInputFile')` is probably getting the wrong element. Not sure why you have an `input` with a type `file` for previewing image, but you can change it to a button.
- You need to add the upload logic to `drop` as well. I suggest moving the drag and drop to the `span` since it covers the area where you want to drop. Your input won't trigger any `change` when `drop` the file.
- You don't need to add classes and set `src` attributes manually using the DOM API. For example, you can add a `isDragging` property to your class. Based on this boolean property, set the `draging` class to the `span`. You can add a `<img src.bind="imageSrc" />` inside `<div id="preview"></div>`. And set the `imageSrc` property inside `dragNdrop` function.

Class:

```
dragNdrop(event) {
   const self = this;
   let fileName = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   self.imageSrc = fileName; // that's it
}

drag() {
  const self = this;
  self.isDragging = true;
}

drop(event) {
  const self = this;
  self.isDragging = false;
  self.dragNdrop(event);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" click.delegate="previewImage()">Preview</button>
<span class="dragBox ${isDragging ? 'draging' : ''}" 
      dragover.delegate="drag()" 
      drop.delegate="drop($event)">

    Click here or drag images here
    <input id="imageInputFile" type="file" change.trigger="dragNdrop($event)" />
</span>

<div id="preview">
   <img show.bind="imageSrc" src.bind="imageSrc" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Matsson updated the answer to demonstrate the `src.bind` fucntionality. You should really consider it since It's much easier than getting the preview `div` element and setting its `innerHTML` (There might be some minor issues since I haven't tested it but you get the idea)